# What is the equivalent method for setQueue in jetty 10?

Tags: java, maven, jetty

Was considering setThreadPool() functionality

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of `QueuedThreadPool` has variations that can do what you need.

As a general tip, if you don't find a setter during your upgrade, check the constructor of the same class.
Also, if you used the latest Jetty 9.x version, enable the deprecated methods and classes reports during your build, as those give you clues on code that need to be resolved before you upgrade (check the javadoc for those same classes for replacements).

**Important note**: *Do not limit QueuedThreadPool with a hard queue limit, you'll impact your server performance and scalability in horrible ways.*

Traditionally, back in the Jetty 6 days people would attempt to limit what Jetty could do by manipulating the threading, which would work.

But over the course of Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 that became untenable (you can thank various EE specs for this change)

By the time Jetty 9 rolled around, attempting to influence behavior by manipulating the ThreadPool is no longer reliable.

Now on Jetty 10 it's actually harmful to reliability to manipulate the thread pool for applying various limits to Jetty.

But all is not lost, there are many existing (and better) techniques (since Jetty 7 days) to limit behaviors on Jetty: requests, resources, connections, pooling, etc

Another option, if you care, is to not use the Jetty default `QueuedThreadPool`, and just use a standard java `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` wrapped with a `org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ExecutorThreadPool` that you pass to the Jetty `new Server(ThreadPool)` constructor.  You'll lose debug and dump features built into Jetty, but it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply; is there a corresponding method from QueuedThreadPool that serves the same setQueue purpose, or how would the third conditional be adjusted to instead pass to constructor?

Comment: Standard Java Constructor behavior, gather up the variables, then use them to construct the QueuedThreadPool object. (all of your variables: minThreads, maxThreads, queue, etc).  Setters that would cause a fault if changed after the LifeCycle of the QueuedThreadPool was started were removed.

Answer (score -1):

```
Server server = new Server();

HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig));

// Set the maximum queue size to 100
connector.setQueueCapacity(100);

server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });

// Start the server
server.start();
```

Comment: This is a different queue, the question is about ThreadPool job queue, not incoming connection (pre-accept) queue.